# Find the interval of $c$ such that the rational function $\frac{x^2+2x+c}{x^2+4x+3c}$ takes all real values

Tags: functions, quadratics, domain-theory

Find the interval of $c$ such that the rational function $$f(x)=\frac{x^2+2x+c}{x^2+4x+3c}$$ takes all real values $\forall$ $x\in D_f$

I tried in the following way:

Let $$y=\frac{x^2+2x+c}{x^2+4x+3c}$$  converting this to a quadratic in $x$ we get

$$(y-1)x^2+x(4y-2)+c(3y-1)=0$$ and since $x \in D_f$ this equation should have Discriminant Non negative

so

$$(4y-2)^2-4c(y-1)(3y-1) \ge 0$$ i.e.,

$$(4-3c)y^2+(4c-4)y+1-c \ge 0$$ since $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}$ the above quadratic is non negative we have two conditions

$$4-3c \gt 0$$ and

$$(4c-4)^2-4(4-3c)(1-c) \lt 0$$

$$4c^2-4c \lt 0$$ so

$c \in (0 \:\: 1)$

Is there any other approach

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
  f(x) &= \frac{x^2+2x+c}{x^2+4x+3c} \\
  &= \frac{x^2+4x+3c - 2x - 2c}{x^2+4x+3c} \\
  &= 1-\frac{2x + 2c}{x^2+4x+3c}
\end{align}

therefore $x^2+4x+3c$ cannot be zero.

$x^2+4x+3c = 0$ has no solution
from discrimant

\begin{align}
  b^2 - 4ac &< 0 \\
  16 & < 12c \\
  3c & > 4 \\
  c & > \frac{4}{3}
\end{align}

however if $2x + 2c$ is also zero, it would take the value, so if $(x + c)$ is a factor of denominator
$x^2 + 4x + 3c = (x + c)(x + 3)$ implies that $cx + 3x = 4x$ so $c = 1$

However at $c = 1$, $x = -3$ cannot be taken.

So $c > \dfrac{4}{3}$.